# Make Cakephp button go to external link

Tags: cakephp

I have a button called 'buy now' where the href is a value from a  gallery_url field.

When I click the button i get a URL like this:

http://localhost:8080/mysite/artworks/view/http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMain_Page

Whereas it should be like this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page

I'm new to Cakephp2, here is my code below

```
       <li>
       <?php echo $this->Html->link('Buy now', array($artwork['Artwork']['gallery_url']), array ('class' => 'btn btn-buy'));?>
       </li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the documentation of Link function in HtmlHelper:

http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.View.Helper.HtmlHelper.html#_link

Supposing that you are using "http://" on your link, what you need to do is delete this "array($link)" of your code. You should pass the second argument as string, not as array.

Try this:

```
<li>
   <?php echo $this->Html->link('Buy now', $artwork['Artwork']['gallery_url'], array ('class' => 'btn btn-buy'));?>
</li>
```